# Default time in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I type Textbox1.text = Today,the date is capturing with default time ie 12:00:00,If instead of today if i code Now ,then also same 12:00:00 is capturing in to the sql database.

Textbox1.text= getdate() is getting error.So can any one help to solve this
Thank You

Comment: still the time is 12:00:00
I want it to be the currect time.

Comment: You haven't given *any* information about how the UI is connected with the database, nor the type of the column in SQL. I suggest you decouple the UI and the database sides of the problem. If you write a small console app and use DateTime.Now to update the database, does that work? Conversely, if you just write the data from the UI to a log file instead of to SQL Server, does that work?

Comment: Textbox1.text = getdate() does not work because getdate() is a SQL Server function, not a VB one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
it is solved

Comment: Problem was in the statement 
command text ="update Paymaster set ...."

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Textbox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
```

That is equivalent to calling ToString("d") on an instance of a date. You can check out other standard format strings on the DateTime.ToString method [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

EDIT: the above will address the presentation side of things for the textbox, but your SQL column is probably a DateTime type which will store a default time if not given. That is why you're seeing the "12:00:00 AM" time portion. When you retrieve the data from SQL you should handle it in your ASP.NET code-behind to format the data as shown above.

Is there anything specific you're trying to achieve with just the date portion? On a related note, here's some food for thought: [Working with Date and/or Time values in SQL Server: Don't Format, Don't Convert -- just use DATETIME](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/29/SQL-Dates-and-Times.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

> DateTime.Now

i.e.

> TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()

HTH! :)